# Don't understand how interactions really work in Spock

Tags: unit-testing, groovy, mocking, spock

Here's a super easy spock test case in Groovy.!! All classes/interface defined in this specification file. (A specification file in spock is simply a test case file).

Cannot seem to understand the workflow. How're mock objects being instantiated, injected, and destroyed in the test case workflow? Any help is appreciated...

The particular issue I'm having is in understanding how the interaction statement: 1*mockURLAdapter.openConnection( ) works. In my understanding, this is simply a validation statement asserting that the method 'openConnection(_)' is called with a non-empty argument. How/Why is it that invoking this assertion causes the method weatherService.run( ) to fail? The exception returned is shown in the code...

```
import spock.lang.Specification

class WeatherServiceImpl {
    private URLAdapter urlAdapter;
    private URLConnection urlConn;

    public WeatherServiceImpl(urlAdapter){
        this.urlAdapter=urlAdapter
    }

    def run(city) {
        urlConn=urlAdapter.openConnection(city)
        return urlConn.getResponseCode()

    }

}

interface URLAdapter {
    def openConnection(city)

}


class WeatherServiceImplSpec extends Specification {

    def mockURLAdapter = Mock(URLAdapter)
    def mockURLConn    = Mock(HttpURLConnection)
    def weatherService=new WeatherServiceImpl(mockURLAdapter);


    def "Need to figure out the effects of lines: 'troublesome' and 'weirdo' "() {
        given:
        mockURLConn.getResponseCode()>> 9999
        mockURLAdapter.openConnection(_)>>mockURLConn;

        when:
        def result=weatherService.run("New York")

        then:
        // Uncommenting line 'troublesome' below throws a null-pointer exception:
        // java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke method getResponseCode() on null object
        //      at WeatherServiceImpl.run(URLAdapterConnectionSpec.groovy:29)
        //      at WeatherServiceImplSpec.delivers events to all subscribers(URLAdapterConnectionSpec.groovy:54)

        // Commenting out line 'troublesome' gives no issue!!

        // Line 'troublesome':
        // 1*mockURLAdapter.openConnection(_)

        // Line 'weirdo':
        // And yet, line 'weirdo' works just fine, commented or not!(i.e. test passes, no exception thrown)!!
        1*mockURLAdapter.openConnection(_)>>mockURLConn;

        //WTH is happening! ?
        result==9999


    }

}
```

Comment: I believe you have already read the [fine manual](http://spockframework.github.io/spock/docs/1.0/interaction_based_testing.html).

Comment: over and over.. lost in the details!

Comment: I don't understand your doubt... Again you are using a Mock when you need a Stub.

Comment: In my understanding, a mock allows for everything from a stub, and more. While mock objects allow stubbing method calls, they also allow for interactions validation.. i.e. 1*mockURLAdapter.open..., 1*mockURLConnection.getResponseCode( ) etc. Yes, for this example, a stub would suffice. But for many other usages, a mock may also be preferred.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are specifying two times what mockURLAdapter should return and the second time you are saying not to return anything, of course it stays with your last decision.

```
// Line 'troublesome':
1 * mockURLAdapter.openConnection(_)
```

This means that when openConnection(_) is called is not going to return anything. If you want to specify interactions then you should put it just in the **then:** clause

The right way to do it should be like this:

```
def "Need to figure out the effects of lines: 'troublesome' and 'weirdo' "() {
        when:
        def result=weatherService.run("New York")

        then:
        1 * mockURLAdapter.openConnection(_) >> mockURLConn;
        1 * mockURLConn.getResponseCode() >> 9999

        result == 9999
}
```

Comment: Hmmm.. thanks! Some colleague from my work eventually did figure that out as well. It is indeed different from Mockito's way of doing things. Infact, for a long while, I was struggling to understand the design (i.e. why this way? ) of coupling method interaction with stubbing. But I guess, it ultimately allows for more flexible mocks and stubs. I.e. first time, return something, and in a second call, return something else... may be better after all.